# List of filenames as argument for mplayer => mplayer doesn't recognize the filenames

Tags: bash, filenames

i want to play some music files with `mplayer` randomly. I don't want to switch the player for that, i want to understand what's wrong here.

```
ThePandaTooth $ ls
file_1.ogg
file_2.ogg
file_3.ogg
```

I know, the output of `ls | sort -R` results in a randomized output of filenames. But I can't play them, with the odd reason, it can't find the file. The sorting is irrelevant here.

```
ThePandaTooth $ mplayer $(ls | sort -R)
Playing file_1.ogg.
Cannot open file 'file_1.ogg': No such file or directory
Failed to open file_1.ogg

Playing file_2.ogg.
Cannot open file 'file_2.ogg': No such file or directory
Failed to open file_2.ogg
```

**EDIT**: Mplaying the files with `mplayer *` works of course.

Comment: Are these dead symlinks?

Comment: nope. normal/regular files.

Comment: Edit in `ls -l`.

Comment: Try `mplayer $(\ls | sort -R)` I bet you have an alias `ls --color=always`.

Comment: exaktly, --color=always was the result. But why is that happeining? what has the color to do with that?  @Jimmij would you consider to rewrite your comment as an answer so i can mark it solved? @ MichaelHomer mplayer $(ls -l) didn't work, even when i unalias ls. ("unknown option --rw....")

Comment: you don't need to unalias it,  you can just reference `ls` with full path: `mplayer $(/bin/ls | sort -R)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very likely that the problem is that you have defined an alias in one of `*rc` files:

```
alias ls='ls --color=always'
```

In such case color codes survive pipe lines and `mplayer` gets filenames surrounded by those codes. You can pass the output of command substitution `$()` to `printf` to see what `mplayer` really receives, e.g.

```
printf '%q\n' $(ls | sort -R)
```

You would see something like

```
$'\E[01;35mFile_1.ogg\E[0m'
$'\E[01;35mFile_2.ogg\E[0m'
$'\E[01;35mFile_3.ogg\E[0m'
```

Obviously `mplayer` reports correctly 'No such file or directory', and prints full problematic file names including the escape codes, but the shell once again interpret these codes as a color, so you only see names in the output what can be confusing.

To pass filenames correctly just run `\ls` or `command ls` or even start new shell with `bash -f`, so that `bash` won't use an alias but native command

```
$ printf '%q\n' $(\ls | sort -R)
File_1.ogg
File_2.ogg
File_3.ogg
```

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think you should be involving `ls` or `sort` at all here. If you want to play the files in a random order, just use the `-shuffle` option:

```
mplayer -shuffle *
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had asked rather for understanding why my approach (which i though should have worked) didn't worked. ==> i wanted primarily understand bash/shell better, than make this problem working. :)

Comment: That's fair enough, although I would say that in general you should avoid parsing `ls`, as it will lead to all sorts of issues aside from the one you've experienced here. For example, if any of your files contained a space or a `*`, you'd have a whole new set of problems!